# Is it standard practise to put headers in /usr/include and put 'foreign/user' created code into /usr/local/lib when one wants to write a toolset?

Tags: linux, gcc, code-organization

In other words:
Do I need to build a static/shared library for every tool I write, put that library in one of the default lib paths and its headers into the default include path?

As it stands now, I have the headers in the default include path, but also the source files.

I apologize if this is a silly question, but I'm brand new to this environment, but from looking at some of my distros packages, this seems to be how it's done.

Answer (score 2):

You should study the [filesystem hierarchy standard (FHS)](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml). In particular, the section about the [`/usr/local`](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_2.3/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY) hierarchy. I.e., your build system should install

- headers somewhere under `/usr/local/include`
- libraries in `/usr/local/lib`
- public binaries in `/usr/local/bin`
- system binaries in `/usr/local/sbin` (usually only programs that require administrative privileges)
- configuration files in `/usr/local/etc`
- architecture independent data in `/usr/local/share`
- man-pages in `/usr/local/man`

IMHO it is most useful to follow the [GNU Makefile conventions](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Directory-Variables.html) when creating your build system, allowing your users to customise the installation directories in a consistent way. Also, your build system should support the [`DESTDIR`](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/DESTDIR.html#DESTDIR) variable, allowing the user to perform the installation in a staging area (e.g. for packaging purposes).

Comment: If you find this answer to be satisfactory, feel free to accept it ;-)